# Why does RealVNC Server Windows credential fail after domain join?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vnc, vncserver, realvnc

I'm deploying computers with VNC server installed. Prior to domain joining, I am able to VNC into the PCs using a local admin account. After domain joining the PCs, I am no longer able to VNC into the PC using that same admin account. Note that I haven't enabled single-sign on in VNC server, but have Windows authentication still selected.

However, I'm still able to log into Windows using that local admin account if I physically login via keyboard/display. This indicates that the local admin account is still active on the PC. Furthermore, I've confirmed that the account is still an admin account, and I've even added it specifically to VNC server allowed users under the "Permissions and Security" tab.

Any ideas as to why VNC server can't authenticate using the Windows password after a domain join?

Comment: What user groups is the user a member of exactly? Edit your question instead of submitting at your comment

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the values for **Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment** you should also provide the relevant logged events before, during, and after a failed login.  Please provide only the minimum amount of information necessary to answer your question

Comment: @Ramhound The local user is part of the Administrators group. Regarding your second comment, what exactly is that a path to? Where do I take the screenshot?

Comment: @Ramhound You're referring to group policies. I don't feel comfortable sharing a screenshot. What do you suggest I look at here?

Comment: @Ramhound Surely there is a specific setting you haven in mind that you're interesting seeing, otherwise you wouldn't be asking for a screenshot? ;D

Comment: Yes; the current values for each group  policy.  Have you asked your IT Administrator at your company for assistance with this task?